# Tramp mode - very slow connect

Tags: tramp, performance

CentOS 7, Emacs 27.1

Suppose I wan to to connect to the remote host (by ssh).

**Approach#1**
Opent Linux terminal and run the next command

```
ssh someLogin@10.222.11.111
```

Type password and after about **3 seconds** I success connected to the remote host.
Nice.

Now I want do same by Emacs.

**Approach#2**

I use Tramp mode.
I my bookmarks I already has link to remote host.
So I only jump to bookmarks like this;

```
mybookmarskEntity  /ssh:someLogin@10.222.11.111:/home/someLoginHome/
```

and wait ... about 30 seconds. And only **after 30 seconds** I success connected to the remote host.

Why so slowly?

Comment: Try without using the bookmarks to compare how it works.

Comment: @prash If use direct Find file (C-x C-f) "/ssh:someLogin@10.222.11.111:/home/opencm/" then connect fast . About 3 seconds.

Comment: You should profile bookmarks and see why there is such a large discrepancy. It might be caused by some setting of yours (that't the more likely scenario), but in the unlikely case that it is a problem with bookmarks, I'm sure the devs would appreciate a bug report.

Answer (score 2):

Very likely you run into a timeout. You could detect this, if you retry your test with `tramp-verbose` set to 10. If you ned assistance in reading Tramp's traces, contact us at ML`tramp-devel@gnu.org` .

Comment: If use direct Find file (C-x C-f) "/ssh:someLogin@10.222.11.111:/home/opencm/" then connect fast . About 3 seconds. Without bookmarks

Comment: As already said, you must partly disable bookmarks until you find the guilty part. If you need assistance in debugging, pls contact us via the `tramp-devel@gnu.org` ML.